# Combining conversion constructor with operator overloading

Tags: c++

Why is the conversion constructor not called implicitly for i2?

```
class NumString
{
    public:
        NumString(const char*  s)
        {
        }

        int operator*( int i)
        {
            return 42;
        }
};


int main(void)
{
    int i1 = (NumString) "string" * 2;  //OK
    int i2 =  "string" * 2;             //ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the compiler doesn't invoke user-defined conversions where there aren't any user-defined types involved.

Answer (score 5):

The expression `"string" * 2` involves just a `const char *` and an `int`, why should the compiler consider `NumString` in any way?

If it worked like you expect, how would the complier be expected to choose the correct conversion if more than one class had a suitable converting constructor?